# javascript fetch delete request with redirect

Tags: javascript, fetch

So i've been using fetch for my ajax-calls lately and found that `DELETE`-requests that are redirected with in my case `302` actually keeps sending delete-requests to the target url the server is redirecting to.

According to the spec at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-redirect-fetch requests of type `POST` that are being redirected should use `GET` to fetch the upcoming url.

So to the question, shouldn't delete/put act the same way as post here? Or have I missed something? Is it something I can solve without reverting back to good old `XMLHttpRequest` or handling redirects manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the request type from POST to GET for 302 responses is a bug that old browsers had and which modern browsers continue to implement for backwards compatibility.

Since they couldn't send DELETE requests, fetch implements 302s correctly and treats them as an actual redirect.

Since you want to convert to a GET request, use a `303 See Other` response instead. (303 and 307 were introduced in HTTP 1.1 to deal with the ambiguity of 302).

> The response to the request can be found under another URI using a GET method. When received in response to a POST (or PUT/DELETE), the client should presume that the server has received the data and should issue a redirect with a separate GET message.

— https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection